# how to remove element from NavigableSet

Tags: java

I have NavigableSet as below, how can I remove the number less than two?

```java
NavigableSet<Integer> ns = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

I want to see the `ns` only contains (2,3)

Comment: `ns = ns.tailSet(2, true);`? Beware that if you'll try to add a key < 2 after, an exception will be thrown, but it depends on what you want to do with this set after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove something from an array/set when iterating you have to use iterator, otherwise you can encounter with [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

```java
NavigableSet<Integer> ns = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
Iterator<Integer> iterator = ns.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer next = iterator.next();
    if (next < 2) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(ns);
```

prints:

```
[2, 3]
```

**Edit:** Also as suggested you can use tailSet function:

```java
NavigableSet<Integer> tailSet = ns.tailSet(2, true);
```

The `true` parameter will let you to include 2 also in your set. And you can't add any other integer into it lower than 2, if you use this second method.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 8, the [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) method on `Collection` can be used:

```java
NavigableSet<Integer> ns = new TreeSet<>(List.of(1,2,3));

ns.removeIf(v -> v < 2);
```